# MYSQL Union and LIKE

Tags: mysql, select, join, union, sql-like

Hey Guys I'm having difficulty adding LIKE into my UNION, it seems to either return anything, or return just the items specified in the UNION depending on the position of my like, example

Full query

```
SELECT  fruits.key, 
        region, location, report_date, 
        inspection_type AS type, 
        customer AS customer_name, 
        customer_number, shipper, po

    FROM reports

JOIN (      ( SELECT `key` , `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`, `location` FROM `berries`       )
    UNION   ( SELECT `key` , `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`, `location` FROM `melons`        )
    UNION   ( SELECT `key` , `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`, `location` FROM `citrus`        )
    UNION   ( SELECT `key` , `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`, `location` FROM `table_grapes`  )
    UNION   ( SELECT `key` , `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`, `location` FROM `tree_fruit`    )
    UNION   ( SELECT `key` , `report_key`, `shipper`, `po`, `commodity`, `label`, `status`, `location` FROM `lot`           )
    ) fruits 

ON inspection_number = fruits.report_key

WHERE fruits.status = '0' OR fruits.status = '1'

ORDER BY report_date DESC
```

returns

```
key     region              location        report_date     type    customer_name   customer_number     shipper     po
17      Great White North   South Holywood  2012-10-21      citrus  Name            206-420-9564        Yao Ming    4215
16      Great White North   Boulder, CO     2012-10-21      citrus  Name            206-420-9564        Hanjin      33215
21      nw                                  1969-12-31      citrus  2               321                 sdfg        sdfgs
20      nw                  sdfgsdfg        1969-12-31      citrus  2               321                 sdfg        sdfg
```

Trying this though

`WHERE fruits.status = '0' OR fruits.status = '1' AND fruits.location LIKE '%Boulder%'`

Returns the exact same instead of just the row with `Boulder` in location.

This on the otherhand will return the row, but not the rest of the information from `reports`

`WHERE fruits.location LIKE '%Bolder%' AND fruits.status = '0' OR fruits.status = '1'

```
key     region              location        report_date     type    customer_name   customer_number     shipper     po
16      Great White North   Boulder, CO     2012-10-21      citrus  Jd Daniel       206-420-9564        Hanjin      33215
```

What is the correct way to do this? I seem to get half of one, or none of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that AND binds harder than OR, which means your where clause ends up as

```
WHERE fruits.status = '0' OR 
     (fruits.status = '1' AND fruits.location LIKE '%Boulder%')
```

What you mean to do is probably

```
WHERE (fruits.status = '0' OR fruits.status = '1') 
   AND fruits.location LIKE '%Boulder%'
```

which means you'll have to add the parentheses around the OR expression.

Answer (score 1):

Never mix ors & ands without puting brackets around them.  This is probably what you want:

```
WHERE (fruits.status = '0' OR fruits.status = '1') AND fruits.location LIKE '%Boulder%'
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope i get what you mean. if so, you need to staple:

```
WHERE fruits.status = '0' OR (fruits.status = '1' AND fruits.location LIKE '%Boulder%')
```

or

```
WHERE (fruits.status = '0' OR fruits.status = '1') AND fruits.location LIKE '%Boulder%'
```

hope that helps :)